# standardize a variable values differently based on another categorical variable in R (Using R Base)

Tags: r

I have a large dataset that has a continuous variable "Cholesterol" for two visits for each participant (each participant has two rows: first visit = Before   & second visit= After). I'd like to standadise cholesterol but I have both Before and After visits merged which will not make my standardisation accurate as it is calculated using the mean and the SD

**USING R BASE**, How can I create a new cholesterol variable standardised based on Visit in the same data set (in this process standardisation should be done twice; once for Before and another time for After, but the output (standardised values) will be in a one variable again following the same structure of this DF

```
DF$Cholesterol<- c( 0.9861551,2.9154158, 3.9302373,2.9453085, 4.2248018,2.4789901, 0.9972635, 0.3879830, 1.1782336, 1.4065341,  1.0495609,1.2750138, 2.8515144, 0.4369885, 2.2410429, 0.7566147,       3.0395565,1.7335131, 1.9242212, 2.4539439, 2.8528908, 0.8432039,1.7002653, 2.3952744,2.6522959, 1.2178764, 2.3426695, 1.9030782,1.1708246,2.7267124)


DF$Visit< -c(Before,After,Before,After,Before,After,Before,After,Before,After,Before,After,Before,After,Before,After,Before,After,Before,After,Before,After,Before,After,Before, After,Before,After,Before,After) 


# the standardisation function I want to apply
standardise <- function(x) {return((x-min(x,na.rm = T))/sd(x,na.rm = T))}
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Can you include some dput of your data.frame? I'm thinking you can do some pivot_wider (with tidyverse) and then do calculations but I'm not sure about the real structure of you data.frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make your data, fix the df$visit assignment, fix the standardise function to be mean rather than min, and then assume each new occasion of before is the next person, pivot to wide format, then mutate our before and after standardised variables:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(1, 30))
df$cholesterol<- c( 0.9861551,2.9154158, 3.9302373,2.9453085, 4.2248018,2.4789901, 0.9972635, 0.3879830, 1.1782336, 1.4065341,  1.0495609,1.2750138, 2.8515144, 0.4369885, 2.2410429, 0.7566147,       3.0395565,1.7335131, 1.9242212, 2.4539439, 2.8528908, 0.8432039,1.7002653, 2.3952744,2.6522959, 1.2178764, 2.3426695, 1.9030782,1.1708246,2.7267124)
df$visit <- rep(c("before", "after"), 15)

standardise <- function(x) {return((x-mean(x,na.rm = T))/sd(x,na.rm = T))}

df <- df %>%
  mutate(person = cumsum(visit == "before"))%>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = visit, id_cols = person, values_from = cholesterol)%>%
  mutate(before_std = standardise(before),
         after_std = standardise(after))
```

gives:

```
   person before after before_std after_std
    <int>  <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
 1      1  0.986 2.92     -1.16     1.33   
 2      2  3.93  2.95      1.63     1.36   
 3      3  4.22  2.48      1.91     0.842  
 4      4  0.997 0.388    -1.15    -1.49   
 5      5  1.18  1.41     -0.979   -0.356  
 6      6  1.05  1.28     -1.10    -0.503  
 7      7  2.85  0.437     0.609   -1.44   
 8      8  2.24  0.757     0.0300  -1.08   
 9      9  3.04  1.73      0.788    0.00940
10     10  1.92  2.45     -0.271    0.814  
11     11  2.85  0.843     0.611   -0.985  
12     12  1.70  2.40     -0.483    0.749  
13     13  2.65  1.22      0.420   -0.567  
14     14  2.34  1.90      0.126    0.199  
15     15  1.17  2.73     -0.986    1.12
```

If you actually want min in your standardise function rather than mean, editing it should be simple enough.

Edited for BaseR solution, but with a cautionary tale that there's probably a much neater solution:

```
df <- data.frame(id = rep(c(seq(1, 15, 1)), each = 2))
df$cholesterol<- c( 0.9861551,2.9154158, 3.9302373,2.9453085, 4.2248018,2.4789901, 0.9972635, 0.3879830, 1.1782336, 1.4065341,  1.0495609,1.2750138, 2.8515144, 0.4369885, 2.2410429, 0.7566147,       3.0395565,1.7335131, 1.9242212, 2.4539439, 2.8528908, 0.8432039,1.7002653, 2.3952744,2.6522959, 1.2178764, 2.3426695, 1.9030782,1.1708246,2.7267124)

df$visit <- rep(c("before", "after"), 15)

df <- reshape(df, direction = "wide", idvar = "id", timevar = "visit")

standardise <- function(x) {return((x-mean(x,na.rm = T))/sd(x,na.rm = T))}

df$before_std <- round(standardise(df$cholesterol.before), 2)
df$aafter_std <- round(standardise(df$cholesterol.after), 2)
```

gives:

```
i id cholesterol.before cholesterol.after before_std after_std
1   1          0.9861551         2.9154158      -1.16      1.33
3   2          3.9302373         2.9453085       1.63      1.36
5   3          4.2248018         2.4789901       1.91      0.84
7   4          0.9972635         0.3879830      -1.15     -1.49
9   5          1.1782336         1.4065341      -0.98     -0.36
11  6          1.0495609         1.2750138      -1.10     -0.50
13  7          2.8515144         0.4369885       0.61     -1.44
15  8          2.2410429         0.7566147       0.03     -1.08
17  9          3.0395565         1.7335131       0.79      0.01
19 10          1.9242212         2.4539439      -0.27      0.81
21 11          2.8528908         0.8432039       0.61     -0.99
23 12          1.7002653         2.3952744      -0.48      0.75
25 13          2.6522959         1.2178764       0.42     -0.57
27 14          2.3426695         1.9030782       0.13      0.20
29 15          1.1708246         2.7267124      -0.99      1.12
```

Comment: Thank you, JpenzerIs.

is it possible to do that using R base?

Comment: I've edited with a base R solution, but I think there would probably be a better way to do it in base should one use it more often.

Comment: Happy to help :)